# linq to sql "Contains"

Tags: asp.net, sql, linq-to-sql

if i have a field in my table that i want to verify exists, how do i use the contains method to determine if it exists.

i would have thought the contains method just takes in a string but it seems to take in my whole linq data object

Comment: you will have to clarify your question a bit if the answers already given are not what you're looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880.aspx) is an extension method for [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) that determines whether a given object is present in the enumerable. That's not what you want here.

I'm guessing that you have a LINQ query like this:

```
IEnumerable<string> productNames = from p in db.Products select p.ProductName;
```

And now you want to verify that the `ProductName` field actually exists to avoid run-time errors. There is actually no need to check that. Try replacing `p.ProductName` by a field that doesn't exist. The compiler will complain.

Of course, this assumes that the actual database schema matches the one used to generate the database class with `MSLinqToSQLGenerator`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to do it with LINQ but you could do:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE _NAME ='MyTable' and COLUMN _NAME='MyColumn'
```

then based on the count returned from the query you will know if the column exists or not.