# LINQ - Comparing a search term with multiple entries against another string with multiple entries

Tags: c#, linq

I have a column called Title in the DB.

and i have a search term coming from the app.

What i have done so far is this:

```
var valsSearch = value.searchTerm.ToLower().Split(" ");
var results = ctx.Links.Select(x =>x.Title).Where(x => valsSearch.Contains(x)).ToList();
```

For example the Title in the DB might be "Ronaldo scores a hattrick" and the searchTerm may be "scores ronaldo"

How do i filter the results when comparing the Title in DB to the searchTerm?

The result should be that the searchTerm when separated are used to filter the values in the Title DB and if there's a match return the result.

Comment: So, neither "Messi scores" nor "Ronaldo trips over" would result in a match? All single words included in the search term must be found in Title for the item to be a match?

Comment: @AstridE. No any words in the searchTerm can match the Title in DB

Comment: Does this answer your question? [linq to sql "Contains"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164100/linq-to-sql-contains)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
var valsSearch = value.searchTerm.ToLower().Split(" ");
var results = ctx.Links.AsEnumerable().Where(x => valsSearch.Any(y => x.Title.ToLower().Contains(y))).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, but no luck, I tried your suggestion

Comment: Can you explain what is wrong? @redoc01

Comment: There is an error:  

System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Links>
    .Where(l => __valsSearch_0
        .Any(y => l.Title.ToLower().Contains(y)))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.'

Comment: Can you try again by adding AsEnumerable() ?@redoc01